# Interacting Dynamic Components within LocatorPane

Tags: dynamic, locator

I am attempting to create a dynamic contour plot of an ellipse with two locators as the foci within a locator pane. The following code has been implemented:

```
a:= Sqrt[c^2 + b^2]
b = 1;
c = 0;

ellipse := (x^2)/(a^2) + (y^2)/(b^2)
plot := Dynamic[ContourPlot[ellipse == 1, {x,-2,2}, {y,-2,2}]

LocatorPane[Dynamic[{ {c,0}, {-c,0} }], plot]
```

When I evaluate this, the plot behaves pretty much as desired except that only one of the locators can be moved.

This is because I placed `-c` inside `Dynamic` as opposed to just the variable `c`. Ordinarily, I would just do something like `Dynamic[{-c,0}, (c = -#)&]`, however, `LocatorPane` requires that I include the full list of locators within a single `Dynamic`.

I want to find a way to apply a function to `Dynamic` that causes the first component of the second locator to take on the value of `-c` while the first locator is using `c`.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

```
b = 1;
ellipse[x_, y_, pt_] := (x^2)/(pt[[1]]^2 + b^2) + (y^2)/(b^2)
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
             Dynamic@ContourPlot[ellipse[x, y, pt] == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
                                Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], 0}]], 
                                           Point[Dynamic[{-First[pt], 0}]]}], Appearance -> None]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Clean! +1. Btw. why `Epilog` needs `Dynamic@Locator` in: `x = {0, 0};
{
 Graphics[{Locator@Dynamic@x}],
 Graphics[{}, Epilog -> {Locator@Dynamic@x}],
 Dynamic[x]
 }`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks:)! You need the `Dynamic[]` to update and the `Locator[]` to know _what_ to display. You may change the `Locator[]` by `Point[]`, for example.

Comment: @Kuba Oh, I see now. Not sure, let me think (or post a question!)

Comment: @Kuba There was a question about "how deep" Dynamic "sees" when it acts on a expression. I believe it is related to that

Comment: @belisarius any idea which one? :)

Comment: @Kuba I think it was Leonid's. I'll fish for it later.

Comment: Actually, I took another look at this solution. Your solution works for this MWE just fine. But, again, this is a MWE and I was hoping to incorporate this into a larger project. All of the movement in this solution is based on a single (invisible) locator. However, I would like something that uses a separate locator for every individual point, because I want to also incorporate other points (locators) that will behave independently. Is there a more general solution to this problem?

Comment: @cbward I'll answer that asap. Meanwhile please return to your previous question and answer all the comments that were left for you there. And please, upvote the answer you already accepted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have done so. Thank you @belisarius.